# Emotion Styled conditionally add snippet of styles

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, emotion

I have a `styled` component:

```js
const StyledBox = styled(Box)(({theme, locked}) => ({
    width: theme.spacing(2.5),
    height: `calc(50% - 12px)`,
    borderColor: grey[500],
    borderStyle: 'solid',
    borderWidth: 0,
    borderLeftWidth: 3,
    position: 'relative',
    left: '25%',
    [theme.breakpoints.down('md')]: {
        left: '12.5%',
    },
}));


const StyledBoxUnlocked = styled(StyledBox)(({theme}) => ({
    borderLeftColor: grey[500],
    borderTopColor: 'transparent',
    borderBottomColor: 'transparent',
    borderTopWidth: 0,
    borderBottomWidth: 0,
}));
```

What I want is to be able to conditionally add the CSS from `StyledBoxUnlocked` to `StyledBox` based on the input of the boolean prop `locked`.

What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: const style = condition ? {…style1, …style2} : style1; ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [ternary operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) and [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to spread the unlocked style into the locked style if the locked property is false

```js
const unlocked = {
    borderLeftColor: grey[500],
    borderTopColor: 'transparent',
    borderBottomColor: 'transparent',
    borderTopWidth: 0,
    borderBottomWidth: 0,
}

const StyledBox = styled(Box)(({ theme, locked }) => ({
    ...(!locked ? unlocked : {}),
    width: theme.spacing(2.5),
    height: `calc(50% - 12px)`,
    borderColor: grey[500],
    borderStyle: 'solid',
    borderWidth: 0,
    borderLeftWidth: 3,
    position: 'relative',
    left: '25%',
    [theme.breakpoints.down('md')]: {
        left: '12.5%',
    },
}));
```